# Получение значения из формы Flask

Tags: python, flask

разбираюсь во Flask на примере простой страницы получения имени пользователя и пароля. При этом код не работает и не возвращает значение.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Вход</title>
    <style>
        h2 {
        background-color: gray;
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        }
        div {
        margit-top: 50%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Автосервис</h2>

{% if message %}
      <p>{{message}}</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type = "text"  name = "username">
      <br>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type = "password" name = "password">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Вход"
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Код Python:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['post', 'get'])
def login():
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'post':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        if username == 'root' and password == 'root':
            message = 'correct'
        else:
            message = 'incorrent'
    return render_template('login.html', message = message)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Советую приучать себя к хорошему и изучить [FlaskForm](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.3/) | [Статья на habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/346342/) (Настоятельно советую прочитать)**

FlaskForm создают формы как объекты для дальнейшей передачи html файлу и обработки на стороне сервера.

Советую вам подробно ознакомиться с документацией и, при необходимости, посмотреть на пример из моего недавнего проекта.

**Вот пример формы из моего проекта**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, BooleanField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo, Email, Length

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Your name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("E-mail", validators=[DataRequired(), Email('Incorrect email')])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm password", validators=[
        DataRequired(), EqualTo("password", message="Passwords must match")])
    description = TextAreaField("Short description (you can fill it later)")
    submit = SubmitField("Let's go!")
```

Далее нужно передать эту форму html странице:

```
form = RegistrationForm()
return render_template("registration.html", form=form)
```

В html (как пример):

```
<form method="post" class="main-registration-form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group main-form-group">
            {{ form.name(id="name", class='main-registration-input', placeholder='Login') }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group main-form-group">
            {{ form.email(id="email", class='main-registration-input', placeholder="Email") }}
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                <span class="main-registration-error">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group main-form-group">
            {{ form.password(id="password", class='main-registration-input', placeholder="Password") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group main-form-group">
            {{ form.confirm_password(id="confirm_password", class='main-registration-input', placeholder="Confirm password") }}
            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                <span class="main-registration-error">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group main-form-group">
            {{ form.description(type="textarea", id="description", class='py-2 main-registration-input main-registration-description', placeholder="Description") }}
        </div>
        {{ form.submit(class='main-registration-button') }}
    </form>
```

**После этого на стороне сервера получим эту форму всё в той же функции рендера страницы**

`form = RegistrationForm()` Мы уже написали (см. выше)
Теперь добавим обработку данных из формы следующим образом:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    // code
```

Как вы могли догадаться из функции, она проверяет валидность формы.
В конце if вы, при необходимости, можете написать новый `render_template` или `redirect`